# How to update an existing excel .ods file?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.9, pyexcel

Once I have read data from a sheet in a .xls file. I want to put that data in a sheet in an existing excel file with .ods extension without changing anything else in the excel file. I tried openpyxl but it doesn't support .ods files so I tried using pyexcel-ods3 but I am still not sure how to use pyexcel-ods3 to update an existing .ods file.

This is the code I tried but its for writing a new .ods excel file and not for updating an existing one

```
from pyexcel_ods3 import save_data

data = OrderedDict()  # from collections import OrderedDict
data.update({"Sheet 1": [[1, 2, 3], [9, 5, 6]]})
data.update({"Sheet 2": [["row 1", "row 2", "row 3"]]})
save_data("your_file.ods", data)
```

I tried finding the code for updating in [pyexcel-ods3 doc](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-ods3) but could not find anything.

Please let me know if there is a code for it in pyexcel-ods3. I am also open to try any new package if it can get this task done. My python version is 3.9.1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't loading the original file in order for it to be changed.

The library doesn't detect that you are looking to change an existing file, if you save a file with the name of a file that exists it will overwrite the existing file.

In order to *amend* a file, you need to load it, potentially recreate the structure in memory, and make you changes, and then save it back to the filesystem.

The relevant piece of code [from the link you posted](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-ods3) is:

```
from pyexcel_ods3 import get_data

data = get_data("your_file.ods")
```

[You can find that section here](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-ods3#read-from-an-ods-file)

The reason why I say "potentially recreate the structure in memory" is because there is no guarantee that it will load the formatting etc. - sometimes openpyxl will drop the formatting for example and only handle the values.